# Is there a way to prioritize traffic in ROS?

Tags: ros, teleoperation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two types of messages in our teleoperation system, i.e. video stream and haptic feedback. So it is important that data rate for haptic feedback should be not less than certain value. For video stream it is much less critical.

Probably, I can experimentally find certain frame rate for video such that haptic feedback is not deteriorated, but it is not very convenient.

Is there a way to do that automatically?

Thanks,
Boris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41581/is-there-a-way-to-prioritize-traffic-in-ros?/) by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3060 on 2012-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I doubt it.

You can use some kind of relay node that manages the bandwidth explicitly.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-08-16**:
topic_tools throttle can throttle bandwidth.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2012-08-17**:
@dornhege: Thanks, looks like it should solve the problem. Will report back once I try it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might be interested in supporting the recent efforts to enable [IPv6 support](http://www.ros.org/news/2012/06/ipv6-support-for-ros-nodes.html) in ROS. IPv4 gives all packets the same best-effort service, but IPv6 allows to [explicitely specify priorities](http://www.netdummy.net/qos.html), namely through the 8-bit *Traffic class* field of the [IPv6 header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet).

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2012-08-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2